# Can't stop function if xmlhttprequest.responseText equals specific value

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, xmlhttprequest

i am using XmlHttp with java servlets as follows:

```
function btnSave_onclick(){

var xmlHttp;
var responseText;

if (condition){

    var para= "someParamsHere";

    var url = "urlHere";

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlHttp.open('post', url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8');
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", para.length);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    xmlHttp.send(para);

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState==4) {
            if(xmlHttp.status==200){
                responseText=xmlHttp.responseText;
                if(responseText=='error'){
                    alert("Fatal Error Occurred");
                    return;
                }
           }
        }
    }

}

// some other code here

}
```

the code post to servlet, and in the servlet if exception occurs i print to the response text contains the string 'error', issue is that the error alert appears but the code continues to the block // some other code here meaning the return doesn't exit the js function, please advise.

Comment: are you sure your response text is actually "error" (lowercase and without trailing spaces)?

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan, as i said it prints the `alert("Fatal Error Occurred");` that means responseText is error as expected, but the issue is that it ignores the return and continues to the next block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the point of "A" in AJAX, i.e. the asynchronicity. The code inside the inner function (`xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() {...HERE...}`) executes asynchronously. This means that the entire outer function (`btnSave_onclick()`) will comlete and at some time later, the `onreadystatechange` will run (if at all). In pseudocode, and assuming `condition === true` for simplicity, your code is:

```
function btnSave_onclick() {
    doAjaxAndWhenItFinishesRun(function(responseText) {
        if( responseText=='error' ) handleFatalError();
        else handleSuccess();
    });
    doStuff();
}
```

Let me rewrite that, but this time without the inner function:

```
function ajaxFinished(responseText) {
    if( responseText=='error' ) handleFatalError();
    else handleSuccess();
}

function btnSave_onclick() {
    doAjaxAndWhenItFinishesRun(ajaxFinished);
    doStuff();
}
```

I believe it is clearer now that `btnSave_onclick()` runs 2 things, the 1st happens to be the async call, and then `doStuff()`. When and *if* the async call finishes, then `ajaxFinished()` is called. The solution, if `doStuff()` is to run only in case of success, is to call it from `handleSuccess()` in the example above, or, in your case, here:

```
function btnSave_onclick(){
    ...
    if (condition){
        ...
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState==4) {
                if(xmlHttp.status==200){
                    responseText=xmlHttp.responseText;
                    if(responseText=='error'){
                        alert("Fatal Error Occurred");
                    }
                    else {
                        // some other code here
                        // ... this code will run on success
                    }
               }
            }
        }
    }

    // any code here will run anyway and BEFORE the AJAX completes
}
```